# Error while iterating through HashMap in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I'm trying to iterate through a HashMap like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Integer value = entry.getValue();
}
```

but I get this error:

```
entry cannot be resolved
```

Is this the wrong way to do it? From what I can tell, this seems to work for others.

Comment: Just curious, why are you iterating over `entrySet()` instead of iterating over `keySet()`? BTW that code works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `Iterator`. [Check out the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: @Jigglypuff if you are using an IDE, then try to clean ur project.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{
    Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = it.next();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Integer value = entry.getValue();
}
```